# How could I make sure that facebook reject my request for authentication plugin

Tags: authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

About 2 weeks ago, the fb login button on my site  was not working. At that time, my site was attacking by some robots.

Is that the reason why my login button was not working anymore? 
How could I make sure? 
Is there any way like email or some form page to contact with the fb manager?

Thanks a lot.

Pokey

Comment: Anything having to do with Facebook administration or policies must be [directed to Facebook](http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/).

Answer (score 1):

if the bots attacking your website didn't affect the content of your page (the Page you store the javascript calling for the Login for Facebook). it wouldn't make sense not to work. Because the login button access the facebook server, if the javascript part on your page of the Facebook Login is correct, even with attacks it would work perfectly. So maybe it's something else. You need to give more details!

Comment: Dear,
We've had done some testing, like creating a new fb app, and use that appid for authentication plugin on the same domain with the same code style, and still not working. 
So mayber it's 90% sure that facebook was banned our doamin.
Does anyone know where to get the facebook's technical support email or other ways? I found nothing.

Thanks.